# pd transpose multiple rows into single column

Tags: pandas, merge, pivot, transpose

Dear friends i want to transpose the following dataframe into a single column. I cant figure out a way to transform it so your help is welcome!! I tried pivottable but sofar no succes

```
X   0.00    1.25    1.75    2.25    2.99    3.25    
X   3.99    4.50    4.75    5.25    5.50    6.00    
X   6.25    6.50    6.75    7.50    8.24    9.00    
X   9.50    9.75    10.25   10.50   10.75   11.25    
X   11.50   11.75   12.00   12.25   12.49   12.75    
X   13.25   13.99   14.25   14.49   14.99   15.50
```

and it should look like this

```
X    
0.00    
1.25    
1.75    
2.25    
2.99    
3.25    
3.99    
4.5    
4.75    
5.25    
5.50    
6.00    
6.25
```

etc..

Comment: Does `df.stack()` do what you need?

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, `df.columns[0]` is used as I don't know what are your headers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': df.set_index(df.columns[0]).stack().reset_index(drop=True)})

df

        X
0    0.00
1    1.25
2    1.75
3    2.25
4    2.99
5    3.25
6    3.99
7    4.50
8    4.75
9    5.25
10   5.50
11   6.00
12   6.25
13   6.50
14   6.75
15   7.50
16   8.24
17   9.00
18   9.50
19   9.75
20  10.25
21  10.50
22  10.75
23  11.25
24  11.50
25  11.75
26  12.00
27  12.25
28  12.49
29  12.75
30  13.25
31  13.99
32  14.25
33  14.49
34  14.99
35  15.50
```

Comment: is it also to divide the stack? into 2 columns with headers X and Y?

Comment: @Bschieland not as easily, it's better to split it into rows with `X` and rows with `Y` and then just stick them together.

Answer (score 0):

ty so much!! A follow up question(a)

Is it also possible to stack the df into 2 columns X and Y
this is the data set

This is the data set. 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7

X   0.00    1.25    1.75    2.25 2.99   3.25

Y   -1.08   -1.07   -1.07   -1.00   -0.81   -0.73

X   3.99    4.50    4.75    5.25    5.50    6.00

Y   -0.37   -0.20   -0.15   -0.17   -0.15   -0.16

X   6.25    6.50    6.75    7.50    8.24    9.00

Y   -0.17   -0.18   -0.24   -0.58   -0.93   -1.24

X   9.50    9.75    10.25   10.50   10.75   11.25

Y   -1.38   -1.42   -1.51   -1.57   -1.64   -1.75

X   11.50   11.75   12.00   12.25   12.49   12.75

Y   -1.89   -2.00   -2.00   -2.04   -2.04   -2.10

X   13.25   13.99   14.25   14.49   14.99   15.50

Y   -2.08   -2.13   -2.18   -2.18   -2.27   -2.46